# Redirect request from Nginx to Spring boot App over https

Tags: java, angular, spring, spring-boot, nginx

I have deployed my angular application in nginx server. Spring boot app is running on same machine with another port. Using openssl I have generated .crt and .key file for nginx conf.

```
 ssl_certificate "/etc/nginx/ssl/nginx.crt";
 ssl_certificate_key "/etc/nginx/ssl/nginx.key";
```

In my spring boot app , I have done the configuration in application.properties as follows:

```
server.require.ssl=true
server.ssl.key-alias=localhostboot
server.ssl.key-password=changeit
server.ssl.key-store=/opt/angular/config/selfsigned.jks
server.ssl.key-store-provider=SUN
server.ssl.key-store-type=JKS
```

Now when my angular make contact to spring boot, I am getting error like ERR:CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID_ERROR.
I think this has something to do with ssl handshake. Can someone provide  some inputs on this.

Comment: Usually in `ssl_certificate` nginx directive you specify the fullchain certificate file (concatenated cert and CA).

Comment: That error means that you have generated and using a self signed certificate. And therefore it can not be trusted and validated. Try to append nginx.crt file with a valid CA certificate.